# Is it possible to bulk add custom fields to all my products in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I got 8,5k products in WooCommerce, and I would like to add a custom field to every product I got. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: It is definitely possible, but because there is no standard way of doing it, you will need to give as much specific information as possible if you're looking to learn how.

Comment: what is the value of custom field , is it same for all products or it differs for each product?!